# Is there a way to tell if a post was edited within the 5 minute window?

Tags: discussion, edits

I understand that you can't see the exact change history, but can you at least see if a post was edited in the past few minutes?

In some circumstances, person A may answer a question.  Then, person B comes around and posts an answer.  Person A then goes back and edits the response to reflect information contributed by person B (rendering the second reply irrelevant).

Comment: See also: [Demarcate edits made after a comment is posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48798/demarcate-edits-made-after-a-comment-is-posted) (should be done for answers as well)

Comment: Related: [Is there an editing 'grace period' on answers after they have been posted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted/9092#9092)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, it's been mentioned<sup>*</sup> that any revisions within the 5 minute window aren't saved, only the final edit in the 5-minute window gets saved, so as of now there's no way to see the edit in the 5-minute window

<sup><sup><sup>*</sup>*Due to certain guidelines, I cannot link to the source quote.*</sup></sup>

Comment: Can you link to the guideline which prohibits you from linking to the source quote?  Also, the fact that the revisions aren't saved doesn't necessarily preclude the possibility of indicating that the post was edited ...

Comment: @Sathya I believe it is indeed stored in the database, but is not displayed to the public and for all purposes, is non-existant.